# Titanium iOS simulator Error

Tags: titanium, simulator

I have been trying to run my project on the iphone simulator in Titanium.  However, this error occurs:

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.8.1 (01/27/12 17:31 a24502a)
[INFO] iPhone Device family: universal
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 5.0
[INFO] iPhone simulated device: iphone
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benedictliang/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.1/iphone/builder.py", line 953, in main
softlink_for_simulator(project_dir,app_dir)
  File "/Users/benedictliang/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.1/iphone/compiler.py", line 178, in softlink_for_simulator
softlink_resources(resources_dir,app_dir)
  File "/Users/benedictliang/Library/Application             Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.1/iphone/compiler.py", line 162, in softlink_resources
os.symlink(from_, to_)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

Could someone help me with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by cleaning the project.

```
Project -> Clean..
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you can't do a project clean (i.e. you imported the project from Github, which sometimes will disable your project clean for some reason), go to the build folder of your project and delete the files from the iphone subfolder.